# How to find the logarithm of two numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

Basically like the opposite of `Math.pow()`.

I want a function which can be used as such a logarithm:

```
var mynum = findpower(36, 6); // 2, because 6 squared is 36
```

How could such a function be constructed?

Comment: I don't get why people downvoted this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)

```
Math.log(36) / Math.log(6) = 2
```

in general case

```
Math.log(number) / Math.log(base)
```

The logarithm has following property: if a = log(n = number, b = base) (usually denoted as log<sub>b</sub>(n)) then b<sup>a</sup> = n. In my code above I used logarithms property: log<sub>y</sub>(x) = log<sub>c</sub>(x) / log<sub>c</sub>(y) where c is any positive number.

`Math.log` in examples above is the natural logarithm, i.e. the logarithm with base = e (≈ 2.718281828…, see Math.E). Obviously, if we have the natural logarithm (usually denoted as ln(n) or log(n)), then we have the logarithm with any other base via the equation given above: log<sub>y</sub>(x) = log(x) / log(y)

Comment: Ok, this question is poor, but the answer didn't match: *How could such a function be constructed?*. As there is not http://math.stackexchange.com/ and the question is tagged `javascript`, a `function` (or `prototype`) could be welcome.

Comment: @F.Hauri, `Math.log(number) / Math.log(base)` is valid javascript code, that works just fine. Isn't it a prototype?